# Accessing Session on POST requests within HttpModule (ASP.NET WebForms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, webforms, httpmodule

I'm working on a cookieless ASP.NET WebForms application that needs to receive a POST request and store the request body into the Session variable. The request is posted to an ASPX page, what I can simulate with Postman. For some reason, I can't handle this within the code behind of the page.

To retrieve the request body I've put some code in the Application_EndRequest handler of an HttpModule, which works okay:

```
public sealed class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.EndRequest += new EventHandler(Application_EndRequest);
    }

    private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        if (req.UrlReferrer == null && 
            req.Url.ToString() == MyEndPoint &&
            req.RequestType.ToUpper() == "POST")
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(req.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
            {
                //here I get the body of the POST request
                var requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //but HttpContext.Current.Session is null
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {}
}
```

However, the session isn't available at that stage when using `HttpContext.Current.Session`. Is there any way to access it?

I've found some people using the `PostRequestHandlerExecute` event instead. However, this handler doesn't seem to hit for the POST request, but for a subsequent GET request where the body of the POST request is no longer available.

Comment: Why cookieless? What's the context for this?

Comment: Who is sending this post request, and, not using cookies, in which session do you want to store your data?

Comment: what kind of post-back we talking about? A button + full page, or say a web service (ajax) call into that page? You  can certainly add some "data" or stuff to a __DoPostBack in JavaScript, but then you posting the whole page back, and thus and then why not just pass the information in a textbox or even a hidden field control?

Comment: Thank you all. The application doesn't use cookies because of a client requirement. It receives JSON data from another application via POST request and returns a URL including the session ID so that other application can redirect users and continue with the session (for cookieless see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100)#cookieless-sessionids)